# v.rectify don't work properly from processing toolbox in QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

I would like to use the tool "v.rectify" from GRASS in my plugin, but when I call it, it continues to say that "ERROR: Required parameter 'output' not set", although this parameter is set. I think this is a bug. I run the tool with the following parameters:

```
{ '-3' : False, '-b' : False, '-o' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001,
'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 1, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None,
'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '','GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '',
'inline_points' : '', 'input' : 'F:/Study/6_semester/manufacturing_practice/Results/
ClipProject.shp', 'order' : 2, 'output' : 'rectified_test', 'points' : 'F:/Study/6_semester/
manufacturing_practice/Work/LinkTable_fixed.txt', 'rmsfile' : 'F:/Users/Ram1L/AppData/Local/
Temp/processing_13eee64d26b245df93f2fdc2e933ecd0/b7cd4c655ce04008af2d038b81108a60/rmsfile.txt',
'separator' : 'pipe' }
```

I tried to use the tool in the GRASS itself with the same parameters and it works. Also tried many times to change the input parameters. QGIS version - 3.2.0-Bonn, GRASS version - 7.4.1, OS - Windows 8.1. Link to the log of tool - https://pastebin.com/tFfLcrNF. Other tool from GRASS section in processing toolbox v.buffer works fine. Sorry for bad english